# Confused about AMD/Intel DDR2 type memory

Tags: processor, memory

I am looking for RAM DDR2 non-ECC, unbuffered, PC2-6400 4GB per one bank to upgrade my old PC. Currently have 4GB on it in four banks. The maximum capacity is 16GB.

I am using an HP desktop that has an Intel CPU on an Intel motherboard.   However, when I google to find RAM I want to purchase, their advertising is always stating that desktop RAM is for AMD only. Is this RAM for AMD CPU only?  Why? How do I find RAM for Intel chip?

Comment: AFAIK there is no vendor locked RAM yet

Comment: Although vendor-locked RAM doesn't exist, occasionally there's RAM that isn't compatible with one platform for one reason or another. Given how inexpensive DDR2 is these days, I'd recommend getting a kit that doesn't claim to be AMD-only. That said, why do you need to upgrade this computer specifically? All DDR2-based platforms are really old at this point; you'd probably be better off using your money to get a newer PC.